# Accessing Controls from another formview inside the same page

Tags: asp.net

I have several forms, each with their own DDL, that I'm using inside a page. I have them in different forms because I need different data sources for each DDL. When I press the Submit button, it gives me an error that it can't find the control "ddlCategory". I assume it is because it is in a different form. Here is the markup:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert" >
    <InsertItemTemplate>    
        Select a Category:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="ORG_NAME" 
            DataValueField="ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
   </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ORGANIZATIONS]"/>
<br />
<asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DefaultMode="Insert" >
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        Select an Organization:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="SectionName"
            DataValueField="ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>    
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
    SelectCommand="SELECT ID,SectionName FROM ORG_SECTIONS WHERE OrgID=@OrgID ">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCategory"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue"
            Name="ID" Type="String"
            DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<br />
<asp:FormView ID="FormView3" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource3" DefaultMode="Insert" >
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        Select an Attorney:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAtty" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource3" DataTextField="Expr1" DataValueField="ATTY_ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource3" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ATTY_ID, NAME & ' ' & INITIAL & ' ' & LASTNAME AS Expr1 FROM ATTORNEYS ORDER BY NAME & INITIAL & ' ' & LASTNAME">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Also, if there is a way to do it inside one formview control, I'd like to know that too.

Comment: Could you please post your code behind and specifically the line that is giving the error? And when you say "different form", do you mean different FormView or actually a different form?

Answer (score 0):

Did it this way:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ORGANIZATIONS]"/>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource3" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ATTY_ID, NAME & ' ' & INITIAL & ' ' & LASTNAME AS Expr1 FROM ATTORNEYS ORDER BY NAME & INITIAL & ' ' & LASTNAME">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<br />
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert" >
    <InsertItemTemplate>    
        Select a Category:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="ORG_NAME" 
            DataValueField="ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server"
        DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb"
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID,SectionName FROM ORG_SECTIONS WHERE OrgID=@OrgID ">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCategory"
                PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                Name="ID" Type="String"
                DefaultValue="" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
        Select an Organization:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="SectionName"
            DataValueField="ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
<br />
        Select an Attorney:<br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAtty" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource3" DataTextField="Expr1" DataValueField="ATTY_ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="AddRec" />
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void AddRec(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ddlCategory");
    DropDownList ddlOrg = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ddlOrg");
    DropDownList ddlAtty = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ddlAtty");

    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\webvideos.mdb;";
    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO [Org_Sec_Atty] ([OrgID], [SecID], [Atty_ID]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

    con.Open();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrgID", ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecID", ddlOrg.SelectedValue);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttyID", ddlAtty.SelectedValue);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("ManageProfAffs.aspx");
}
```

And done.